# Как задать конкретную длину строкового атрибута класса на python?

Tags: python, ооп, классы, атрибуты

Необходимо написать класс, каждый экземпляр которого имеет обязательный строковый атрибут (например 'str_attr') длиной ровно 10 символов. Как наложить такое ограничение на атрибут?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать свойства:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._str_attr = None

    @property
    def str_attr(self):
        return self._str_attr

    @str_attr.setter
    def str_attr(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            raise ValueError('Значение должно быть строкой')
        if len(value) > 10:
            raise ValueError('Слишком длинная строка')
        self._str_attr = value


some_obj = SomeClass()
some_obj.str_attr = 'Hello'
```

Comment: Спасибо! Буду разбираться, как это устроено. Ваш код работает, если исправить на @property.

Comment: @VladRiabets [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Таким образом, мы задаём значение атрибута после инициации экземпляра.  То есть мы не можем наложить это ограничение на атрибут, создаваемый вместе с экземпляром в __init__?

Comment: @VladRiabets можем, ничто не мешает обращаться к свойствам из конструктора.

Comment: кстати, может быть, всё просто и можно сделать так (вроде работает):                  class Myclass:
    def __init__(self, str_attr):
        if len(str_attr) != 5:
            raise ValueError('Неверная длина строки!')
        self.str_attr = str_attr

Comment: @VladRiabets можно, но это не помешает после создания объекта присвоить атрибуту что попало.

Comment: Да, точно. Прочитал про декораторы, используемые в вашем коде. Теперь вижу полную картину. Спасибо за ответ и пояснения!